Tensor product of modules over commutative vs non-commutative rings
(I) Let $M,N$ be $R$-modules where $R$ is commutative ring with unity. The tensor product of $M$ with $N$ over $R$ is constructed by

take free-abelian group on $M\times N$
take quotient of this group by the subgroup generated by
$$(m_1+m_2,n)-(m_1,n)-(m_2,n)$$
$$(m,n_1+n_2)-(m,n_1)-(m,n_2)$$
$$(rm,n)-r(m,n)$$
$$(m,rn)-r(m,n).$$
The elements of quotient group are written in a form
$$
\sum_i (m_i\otimes n_i) \,\,\,\,\,\,\, (finite \,\,\,sum)
$$
To the quotient group we give an $R$-module structure by
$$
a\cdot \sum_i (m_i\otimes n_i)=\sum_i (am_i \otimes n_i).
$$

(II) The definition of tensor product over non-commutative ring $R$ considers

right $R$-module $M$;
left $R$-module $N$;
and then quotient of free abelian group on $M\times N$ by a subgroup generated by
$$(m_1+m_2,n)-(m_1,n)-(m_2,n)$$
$$(m,n_1+n_2)-(m,n_1)-(m,n_2)$$
$$(mr,n)-(m,rn).$$

Question: If $R$ is non-commutative ring with identity, and if we take left $R$-modules $M$ and $N$, what is the difficulty if we make their tensor product as in the first way?
Why should we consider one module to be left and other to be right (when $R=$ non-commut.)?

Does this question and answer help or relate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111851/tensor-product-of-two-left-r-modules-a-and-b?

If you include $(rm,n)-r(m,n)$ and $(m,rn)-r(m,n)$ in your quotient, then for any $r,s$ you'd have
$(rm,sn)=r(m,sn)=sr(m,n)$ and
$(rm,sn)=s(rm,n)=rs(m,n)$.
If, say $M=N=R$, then when $m=n=1$ and $n=1$ you'd have $rs=sr$.

You might regroup and ask "How about saying $(rm,n)=(m, rn)$ for all $m,n,r$?"  Then on one hand $(rsm,n)=(m, rsn)$ but on the other $(rsm,n)=(sm,rn)=(m,srn)$.  As in the example above we would have a case where $rs=sr$.

So there are sort of two things going on:

There's no longer a good candidate for a module action on $M\otimes_R N$ , so we can't talk about the first definition.
Keeping coefficients on the same side leads to this swapping problem.

You don't run into this when you put things on opposite sides:
If we enforce $(mr,n)=(m,rn)$, then $(mrs,n)=(m,rsn)$ and also $(mrs,n)=(mr,sn)=(m,rsn)$, and there's no swapping.
